# GSP if test returning false while checking if a logged user with Spring Security Core Plugin is the creator of a domain class instance

Tags: grails, spring-security, gsp

I am using [Spring security core plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/spring-security-core).

I want to test if the logged user is the creator of a Note. Note is Grails domain class. Note.creator is User which is my User domain class for Spring Security Core plugin.

The next code does not work

```
<g:set var="loggedUserId"><sec:loggedInUserInfo field="id"/></g:set>
<g:if test="${note.creator.id == loggedUserId}">
   Never jumps here
</g:if>
```

However, If I include both values in separated lines, the output of both is the same

```
${note.creator.id}
${loggedUserId}
```

Any idea what I am missing? Thanks in advanced!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<g:if test="${note.creator.id.toString() == loggedUserId.toString()}">
```

Try like that maybe, loggedInUserInfo returns a string and creatorId is supposedly a long, so equation without cast wouldn't be true.

You should put logic like that into a taglib though.

Answer (score 1):

The tag `<sec:loggedInUserInfo field="id"/>` is not the instance of `Long` you are expecting, it is an instance of `class org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.util.StreamCharBuffer`.  Get the current user in your controller like this:

```
class YourController{    
    def springSecurityService //Inject the Spring Security Service dependency
    //...
    def yourAction ={
        //...
        def currentUser = springSecurityService.getCurrentUser()
        //...
        [currentUser:currentUser] //Make sure to map everything else that needs to be mapped too.
    }
}
```

Then check the current user in your view like this:

```
<g:if test="${note.creator == currentUser}">
   Never jumps here <!--Now it will get in here just fine.-->
</g:if>
```